# ! Missing insert. <inserted text> $ .... with \href{...}{...}

Tags: miktex, texmaker, href

I have this in a document:

```
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_\(something)}
```

I get multiple errors like this:

> ! Missing $ inserted." ....

I supposed that I should escape the parentheses but I didn't find the right way to do it yet. Also I'm not sure about this.

Comment: show a complete example, that makes it *much* easier to test your issue.

Comment: You escaped the wrong bit: You want to escape `_` to `\_` not the `(`: You want `\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something\_(something)}`. **But** in *this* specific example `\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something}` would be much easier. `\href` only makes sense if link target and text differ.

Comment: @moewe : Thank you. I you post this as answer I could select it as solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You escaped the wrong bit: You want to escape `_` to `\_`. There is no need to escape the `(`

```
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something\_(something)}
```

In *this* specific example it seems that

```
\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}
```

would be much easier. Possibly with `\urlstyle{same}` if you don't want URLs in monospace font.

`\href` only makes sense if link target and text differ. Even then `\nolinkurl` might be a good choice

```
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something\_(something)}

\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}

\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(something)}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Regarding url/href ... I knew about it but if I test it now, url renders differently. I think that I have defined a custom style for href. Also, this was the final touch to a relatively long work so I don't think I will got through each link in the document in case href could be replaced by url ;-)

Comment: @TTT You may be able to get the same result for `\href` and `\url` with `\urlstyle{same}`. The advantage of `\url` and `\nolinkurl` is that they allow for URL-specific line breaking. Something to keep in mind for your next project.